# How to make a pane clickable (onAction) in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, pane

Do somebody have an idea how to make a pane, let's say an anchor pane clickable in JavaFX? By clickable I mean a trick, that makes possible for me to set a method for a pane with OnAction in SceneBuilder.

If you know a trick, please share, thanks!

Comment: Are you looking to make it fire `ActionEvent`s, or do you just need it to respond to mouse clicks?

Comment: just to respond, the plan is: I have a split pane. The left side of it is gonna contain a kind of menu. I would like to make it slide out if clicked on it (by setting the divider position to zero) and slide back in if clicked again.

Comment: So can't you just use `onMouseClicked`?

Comment: But yes! Thanks, sorry I am very inexperienced with it, and as the OnAction wasn't there right on the top of the list, I didn't pay enough attention to the rest.

By the way, the best would be, if even the divider's edge would be clickable, is that solvable too? Because as I can see, I can only choose the left pane or the right pane, or the whole split pane, but not the left pane and the dividing edge? Or I am just not seeing something obvious again?